# How to get a string of unique value from a text file in bash

Tags: string, bash

I have a text file of values and I want a string representnig the unique values in the text file with no header.

Example:

file.txt

```
a  
b  
b  
c  
a  
c  
b
```

The result I want is a string with the unique value in the text file, separated by a space.

Result:

```
"a b c"
```

Comment: What did you try? There are tons of questions on how to get unique rows, and how to replace newlines with spaces.

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I am new in bash coding and I don't really know what to do

Comment: Use `sort -u` to get rid of duplicates, and `tr` to convert newlines to spaces to get them all on one line.

Comment: Are the trailing spaces part of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power of `bash` comes from combining different tools. Consider it a construction set that allows to build arbitrary tools for any given purpose on the fly :-)

You are probably looking for something like that:

```
cat data.txt | sort -biu | tr "\n" " "
```

Here "data.txt" refers to a file that holds your data. Depending on the operating system you execute this on you might have to twist the coding of the line break ("\n").

That line does the following:

1. `cat data.txt`
   This outputs the contents of that file, here to `stdout`.
2. `sort -biu`
   This reads data from `stdin`, sorts the contained data and takes care of uniqueness, then writes the result to `stdout`.
3. `tr "\n" " "`
   This reads data from `stdin`, converts the character `\n` to the character  , then writes the result to `stdout`.

The pipe symbols (`|`) inbetween those commands direct the output of the left command to the input of the right command. That way the three commands are combined to a chain of commands and act like a single one, with the functional combination of the three.

Comment: `cat data.txt | sort -biu` = `sort -biu data.txt` (see https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award), that script won't add the leading/trailing `"`s the OP asked for, and `tr "\n" " "` will convert the output into something that's no longer a valid text file and add a trailing blank.

Comment: @EdMorton-SOstopbullying These points certainly are interesting, but subject to interpretation of the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '!seen[$1]++{out=out sep $1; sep=OFS} END{print "\"" out "\""}' file
"a b c"
```